# Starting a new line in a Microsoft Access text box

Tags: ms-access

So I am creating a database and need to enter two titles into a text box. I want to type the first one, and when I am done I try to hit "enter" to jump down to the next line but all it does is save what I entered and exit the text box. What I am doing wrong? I'm so used to just hitting "enter" when I'm in Microsoft Word to start a new line but that does not seem to be how it works in Access.

Answer (score 1):

Press control-enter to get a newline.

Just a tip: If you are entering two values in a single field like that, you have a badly designed table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Is this text box in a table/query grid view or is it a control on a form? If it's on a form, then in design mode there is a property of the text box called `Enter key behaviour` that you can use to determine whether focus should jump to the next control or a new line should be entered within the text box (as you're after).